# Add a CSS class by formControlName

Tags: angular, forms, controls, reactive

I need to **access** in runtime to some controls by **formControlName** and **add a CSS class**.

I've searched a lot including official documentation and here and I couldn't find how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with any other attribute, attribute selector can be used to specify style:

```
  [formControlName="foo"] {
    color: red;
  }
```

If it's a class and not a that should be added, this can be done with a directive:

```
@Directive({ selector: '[formControlName]' })
class FCNDirective {
  @Input() formControlName;

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private renderer2: Renderer2) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.renderer2.addClass(this.elementRef.nativeElement, this.formControlName);
  }
}
```